# How to get Constraints annotation in Play! framework scala template helper?

Tags: scala, templates, playframework, annotations, jquery-easyui

I 'd like to write a helper that generates code for easyui in Play! 2.2.3. In my model, I have a field,eg

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model{    
...
@Required
@Email
public String email;
...
}
```

i'd like to generate html input code like this:

```
<td>Email</td>
<td><input class="easyui-validatebox" type="text" name="email" data-ptions="required:true,validType:'email'"></td>
```

so I write a template like this:

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)

<tr>
    <td><label for="@elements.id">@elements.label</label></td>
    <td class="@if(elements.hasErrors) {error}">@elements.input</td>
</tr>
```

However, is that possible to get my annotations(ie. required,email) in the template?If I know the field is required, then I put a required:true option in data-options.

Looking forward for any replies!

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? I'm in the same boat